# Normal Sylow subgroups in a group of square free order

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> If $|G|=n$ with $n$ square free then there exists at least a normal Sylow subgroup?

Any suggestion are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: 1) Is free squared = square free = a product of different primes? (no divisible por un cuadrado)? 2) What do you mean by "there exists *almost* a Sylow..."?

Comment: See here for example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6078/can-g-of-order-pqr-be-simple-if-its-generated-by-elements-of-orders-p-q/6093#6093